# Error importing org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable/Type?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle, annotations

IntelliJ doesn't seem to yell at me if I have `import org.hibernate.annotations.*`, but if I want to use the `@Type` or `@Immutable` annotations from `org.hibernate.annotations.Type` and `org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable`, IntelliJ tells me that `Cannot resolve symbol 'Immutable'`, and the same for `Type`.

Even when I explicitly import the classes I want, I still get the errors.

I'm using it like this:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;      // Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Type'
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable; // Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Immutable'
import ...(other stuff)

@Entity
@Table(name = "T1")
@Immutable  // Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Immutable'
public class Info {

    @Column(name = "A_DATE")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime") // Error: cannot resolve symbol 'Type'
    private DateTime myDate;

    ...(other stuff)
}
```

Additionally, my `build.gradle` file has the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.2.3.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:1.3.0.Final"
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.3.Final'
    ...(other stuff)
}
```

I've cleaned and rebuilt the project using Gradle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in build.gradle. This should resolve issue.

```
'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to fix the problem, unfortunately :(